# Numerical issues in solving linear systems

Tags: numerical-analysis, error-estimation, matrix

There was an exam in the class. The course is "High Performance Scientific Computing". One of the question in the exam is as follows:

> Consider the linear system
>
> $$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
> with $a,b>0$.
>
> a) If $a$ is very similar to $b$, what is the numerical difficulty in solving this linear system?
>
> b) Suggest a numerically stable formula for computing $z = x + y$ given $a$ and $b$.

This is a Computer Engineering course, however I am not able to answer these questions. What is the keyword to find a solution on the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $2\times 2$ matrix has determinant close to zero, and so its [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices) is very large, causing numerical instability.

The explicit solution of your system is
$$
x=\frac{a}{a^2-b^2}, y=-\frac{b}{a^2-b^2}.
$$
Therefore
$$
x+y = \frac{a-b}{a^2-b^2} = \frac{1}{a+b},
$$
thus avoiding the numerical issues.